# Output text over MIDI to DX7

Tags: midi

I am building a raspi device for my dad to send files to a Yamaha DX7 keyboard. The way it was explained to me, It uses regular text files to tell the synth how to play the notes (as in, how it sounds) As my dad explained it he says it receives the text over regular MIDI protocols and doesn't need any special drivers to send it. Beings a bit of a noob to both the pi and nineteen-eighty-something musical equipment, several googling sessions revealed nothing, so I figured I'd ask here. If anyone knows what to do, it would be greatly appreciated.

tl;dr  How do I use a python script to send text over MIDI?
(via a USB to MIDI adapter, if that matters)

Answer (score 1):

MIDI (Musical Instrument Digital Interface) is a simplex serial protocol (that is only sends data one way. If my memory serves it uses a standard uart. My first thought would be fire up minicom open up the usb midi adaptor tty device and set it to n81 31250 baud, then just do an ascii transfer. the two issues Are that that is a nonstandard baud rate, and something in my mind wants to say even parity which would mean 7 data bit. Give her a try, It can't hurt.

Comment: MIDI ports are not available as TTY devices.

Answer (score 1):

The DX7 uses the normal MIDI protocol, which has nothing to do with text.

The USB/MIDI adapter will show up as a normal MIDI port, and you can use any sequencer to play back MIDI files.

On the command line, use `amidi` or `aplaymidi`.
There are Python libraries for accessing the ALSA sequencer, but if you already have a .mid or .syx file, it might be easier to just run one of these tools.